# How to change slick2d upper left icon

Tags: java, icons, image, slick2d

Hey guys I was wondering if there was a way to change he upper left icon in slick2d. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html#setIcon(java.lang.String) you should call setIcon(java.lang.String ref) of your container's instance